# MaybeUninit and initialization of ZST/uninhabbited/one-representation types in Rust

Tags: rust, initialization

The question is simple but I haven't been able to find the answer. Is the following piece of code valid/safe in Rust:

```rust
use core::mem::MaybeUninit;

// This is a ZST
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

// This is an uninhabited type
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum {}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum OneVariantEnum {
    Variant1,
}

fn main() {
    let s: MaybeUninit<MyStruct> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    println!("s: {:?}", unsafe { s.assume_init() });

    let e: MaybeUninit<MyEnum> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    println!("e: {:?}", unsafe { e.assume_init() });

    // and what about this?
    let o: MaybeUninit<OneVariantEnum> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    println!("o: {:?}", unsafe { o.assume_init() });
}
```

Comment: Please post working code. The code isn't valid Rust code to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following seems correct, because `MyStruct` is a ZST:

```rust
let s: MaybeUninit<MyStruct> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
println!("s: {:?}", unsafe { s.assume_init() });
```

---

Constructing a value of an uninhabited type is however always UB, so the following is not correct:

```rust
let e: MaybeUninit<MyEnum> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
println!("e: {:?}", unsafe { e.assume_init() });
```

In debug mode, Rust *might* catch this and panic with

> thread 'main' panicked at 'attempted to instantiate uninhabited type `MyEnum`'

---

As for `OneVariantEnum`, it is a ZST, so it is similar to `MyStruct` and the following does not involve UB:

```rust
let o: MaybeUninit<OneVariantEnum> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
println!("o: {:?}", unsafe { o.assume_init() });
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `MaybeUninit::assume_init()` is to convert memory initialized after the call to `MaybeUninit::uninit()` into valid values. If the type is zero-sized, then `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()` (UB for most types) is actually valid because there is simply no memory to initialize. If it weren't valid, then there would be *no* way to create ZSTs using `MaybeUninit`, and such a limitation is not mentioned in the documentation.

[This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/4272) contains a discussion that confirms this in passing.

Note that the above only applies to ZSTs, not to uninhabited types, so constructing `MyEnum` is never allowed and that example is UB.

Comment: “The whole point of `MaybeUninit::assume_init()` is to convert memory written to after the call to `MaybeUninit::uninit()` into valid values”. This is incorrect. `assume_init` cannot know how to do this conversion, and it's the user responsibility to make sure a valid value was written. This is was `assume_init` is `unsafe`.

Comment: @mcarton By "conversion" I didn't mean changing the contents of the - memory this is why I said "written to after the call to `uninit` - the writing is a separate step, but conversion at the type system level, by emitting the appropriate compiler intrinsics to make the values valid and not UB (which I mention in the question). I believe the answer is correct as it stands, but I'd certainly accept suggestions how to make it clearer to avoid the misunderstanding. Additionally I've now corrected the answer to mention that constructing `MyEnum` is UB, which I did miss.

Comment: Re: *If [`assume_init` on an uninitialized `MaybeUninit<Zst>`] weren't valid, then there would be no way to create ZSTs using MaybeUninit* -- this is simply not true; you can still use `as_mut_ptr` + `ptr::write` an initialized `Zst` value (or `MaybeUninit::write` on nightly) and then call `assume_init` the same way you would with any non-zero-sized type.

Comment: Regarding "convert memory... into valid values", I also don't think this is right. It sounds like you're talking about something like LLVM's `freeze` instruction, which is not really accessible in Rust today. Perhaps that's not what you meant, but that's what it sounds like

Comment: @trentcl But what would be the purpose of `ptr::write()` on a ZST? I'm confused as to what point you're trying to make here. "Converting memory into valid values" is just a way of *describing* what `assume_init()` does, which is take the memory of `MaybeUninit` and actually returning a usable value. I'm not familiar with `freeze()` so I can't comment whether it's relevant.

Comment: The answer suggests that `assume_init` actually *does something* to the memory, or emits some kind of code that marks the memory location as having a valid value. For instance, from your answer, I would be led to believe that [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0eb3852b4fdef6d9ceb3d86290dcebfc) is UB, because there's no call to `assume_init` before the inner value is used. However, this code is not UB.

Comment: @trentcl Good point and example; I've now removed the part about "compiler fences and UB" which was too hand-wavy anyway.